# loop through set of values, compare and increase count

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a set of values in the types column

```
types
ABC
EVAL
IBC
ABC
IBC
IBC
EVAL
```

I want to loop  from first row and compare with the next value, each time the values are different I want to increase the count. For Example if I compare first value with second ABC = EVAL as they are diff I want to increase the count. In the next round I will compare value 2nd row with value from 3rd row i.e EVAL=IBC and again as they are diff I want to increase the count.

I tried using cursor but I am not able to get the next column value in the cursor.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the next row" in a relational database unless you can specify a column to sort by. How do you define the order of rows from that table? Do you have an additional column that you can use to sort the rows?

Comment: so do I need to create another column which starts from value 2 of the first column and then compare them? sorry I am confused about the possible solution...

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **not** "sorted". So your requirement "compare the _next_ value, can only make sense if you can define some sort order on the rows. The "order" of rows you have shown, is not guaranteed. The select statement can return the rows in a totally different order in the next hour and yet another order tomorrow.

Comment: oh sorry, yes I get your point. In my select statement I am sorting the rows by last change time stamp.

Answer (score 3):

To access the next row in a sorted result, you can use the `lead()` function:

You you could use something like this as the statement for your cursor:

```
select value, 
       lead(value) over (order by last_change) as next_value
from the_table
order by last_change;
```

Comment: brilliant! exactly what I needed. cursor works fine now as rows are next to each other. thanks.

Comment: @Makster, If you're just looking for a count, don't bother with a cursor.  Just wrap the above with "select count(*) as counter from (" ... "where value = next_value;"

Comment: Thanks Mark. That is what I did in the end as per your suggestion. Problem is the sql takes a long time to return the count. But when I call a procedure it is almost instant.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case doesn't allow you to use a single query with lead() function, you can do this.

Set up:

```
create table temp_tab(
  t varchar(10),
  last_change date
);

insert into temp_tab values ('ABC',sysdate);
insert into temp_tab values ('EVAL',sysdate);
insert into temp_tab values ('IBC',sysdate);
insert into temp_tab values ('ABC',sysdate);
insert into temp_tab values ('IBC',sysdate);
insert into temp_tab values ('IBC',sysdate);
insert into temp_tab values ('EVAL',sysdate);
```

Loop and increase count:

```
declare
  counter number := 0;
  prev_val varchar(10);

  cursor getRecords is 
  select t
  from temp_tab
  order by last_change;

begin
  -- loop through the cursor
  for c in getRecords loop
    dbms_output.put_line('c.t: ' || c.t);
    -- if the cursor value is the same as the previous value increment the counter
    if (prev_val = c.t) then
      counter := counter + 1;
    end if;
    -- set the previous value equal to the current cursor value
    prev_val := c.t;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('counter: ' || counter);
end;
```

You get output like this:

```
c.t: ABC
c.t: EVAL
c.t: IBC
c.t: ABC
c.t: IBC
c.t: IBC
c.t: EVAL
counter: 1
```